# Perl Regex, Sorting groups with multiple matches into respective arrays

Tags: regex, perl

So I separated a statement using regular expressions into 3 groups.

Group 1: My dog likes to go for a walk, My cat likes to go for a swim, My turtle likes to go for a nap.

Group 2: (.*) words between "my" and "likes"

Group 3: (.*) last three words after "for a"

```
#original statement
$p = "My dog likes to go for a walk
    My cat likes to go for a swim
    My turtle likes to go for a nap"

#regular expression used
$p =~ /((^My (.*) likes to go for a(.*)))/gm);
```

Array 1: ["My dog likes to go for a walk", "My cat likes to go for a swim", "My turtle likes to go for a nap"]

Array 2: ["dog", "cat", "turtle"]

Array 3: ["walk", "nap", "swim"]

Need help putting each group into these respective arrays

Comment: putting each group into respective arrays.

Comment: group 2 and group 3, each of the (.*)

Comment: groups the ones separated by the parenthesis, and each group has a respective match that is denoted as $1, $2, $3

Answer (score 1):

```perl
my (@array1, @array2, @array3);
while ( $p =~ /^(My (.*) likes to go for a (.*))/gm ) {
   push @array1, $1;
   push @array2, $2;
   push @array3, $3;
}
```

Avoiding global vars could be done as follows:

```perl
my (@array1, @array2, @array3);
for my $line (split /\n/, $p)
   if ( my ($pet, $verb) = /^My (.*) likes to go for a (.*)/ ) {
      push @array1, $line;
      push @array2, $pet;
      push @array3, $verb;
   }
}
```

Parallel arrays are a bit cumbersome. An AoA approach is more common.

```perl
my @array;
for my $line (split /\n/, $p)
   if ( my ($pet, $verb) = /^My (.*) likes to go for a (.*)/ ) {
      push @array, [ $line, $pet, $verb ];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $p = "
    My dog likes to go for a walk
    My cat likes to go for a swim
    My turtle likes to go for a nap
";
    
my $re = qr/(My (\S+) likes to go for a (\S+))/;
my $count = 0;
my @arrays;

(
   $arrays[0][$count],
   $arrays[1][$count], 
   $arrays[2][$count++]
 ) = ($1,$2,$3) while $p =~ /$re/gm;

say Dumper(\@arrays);
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'My dog likes to go for a walk',
            'My cat likes to go for a swim',
            'My turtle likes to go for a nap'
          ],
          [
            'dog',
            'cat',
            'turtle'
          ],
          [
            'walk',
            'swim',
            'nap'
          ]
        ];
```

If for any reason OP still prefers separate arrays instead of **AoA** then code slightly different

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $p = "
    My dog likes to go for a walk
    My cat likes to go for a swim
    My turtle likes to go for a nap
";
    
my $re = qr/(My (\S+) likes to go for a (\S+))/;
my $count = 0;
my(@array_1,@array_2,@array_3);

(
   $array_1[$count],
   $array_2[$count], 
   $array_3[$count++]
 ) = ($1,$2,$3) while $p =~ /$re/gm;

say '-- Array 1 --';
say for @array_1;
say '-- Array 2 --';
say for @array_2;
say '-- Array 3 --';
say for @array_3;
```

Output

```
-- Array 1 --
My dog likes to go for a walk
My cat likes to go for a swim
My turtle likes to go for a nap
-- Array 2 --
dog
cat
turtle
-- Array 3 --
walk
swim
nap
```